# Google Sign In JMeter , not able to log in

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to perform load test on one of my site , which has google sign In button , how do I logged in one time and then request for specific page 10 times .

Recording controller also does not did the work , is there something other way around.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? Please post some relevant code.

Comment: I tried to record flow using HTTP(S) recorder , that's all , .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your site is using [OAuth](https://oauth.net/) so record and replay and even correlation won't help as it is too specific.

OAuth authentication is all about obtaining a token (see [User Authentication with OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/)) and passing it along with your credentials via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

There are several ways of obatining an OAuth token, see [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for your response , can you provide me sample structure for same.